# C++ : std::atomic<bool> and volatile bool

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm just reading the C++ concurrency in action book by Anthony Williams.
There is this classic example with two threads, one produce data, the other one consumes the data and A.W. wrote that code pretty clear :

```
std::vector<int> data;
std::atomic<bool> data_ready(false);

void reader_thread()
{
    while(!data_ready.load())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep(std::milliseconds(1));
    }
    std::cout << "The answer=" << data[0] << "\n";
}

void writer_thread()
{
    data.push_back(42);
    data_ready = true;
}
```

And I really don't understand why this code differs from one where I'd use a classic volatile bool instead of the atomic one.
If someone could open my mind on the subject, I'd be grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: With a regular `bool`, the optimizer might rearrange your code to only check the value of `data_ready` once since (naively) its value cannot change once the `while` is entered, producing an infinite loop.

Comment: @dlf: Only if it can prove that `sleep` won't affect the value.

Comment: @dlf I'm Ok with that, i should added volatile bool as Max Truxa said to be sure that the data is load from memory and not cache memory

Comment: If you load and store the atomic<bool> with memory_order_relaxed, there's no difference to a volatile bool. So in this case it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 21):

A "classic" `bool`, as you put it, would not work reliably (if at all). One reason for this is that the compiler could (and most likely does, at least with optimizations enabled) load `data_ready` only once from memory, because there is no indication that it ever changes in the context of `reader_thread`.

You could work around this problem by using `volatile bool` to enforce loading it every time (which would probably seem to work) but this would still be undefined behavior regarding the C++ standard because the access to the variable is neither synchronized nor atomic.

You could enforce synchronization using the locking facilities from the [mutex header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/mutex), but this would introduce (in your example) unnecessary overhead (hence `std::atomic`).

---

The problem with `volatile` is that it only guarantees that instructions are not omitted and the instruction ordering is preserved. `volatile` **does not** guarantee a memory barrier to enforce cache coherence. What this means is that `writer_thread` on processor A can write the value to it's cache (and maybe even to the main memory) without `reader_thread` on processor B seeing it, because the cache of processor B is not consistent with the cache of processor A. For a more thorough explanation see [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#Out-of-order_execution_versus_compiler_reordering_optimizations) and [cache coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) on Wikipedia.

---

There can be additional problems with more complex expressions than `x = y` (i.e. `x += y`) that would require synchronization through a lock (or in this simple case an atomic `+=`) to ensure the value of `x` does not change during processing.

`x += y` for example is actually:

- read `x`
- compute `x + y`
- write result back to `x`

If a context switch to another thread occurs during the computation this can result in something like this (2 threads, both doing `x += 2`; assuming `x = 0`):

```
Thread A                 Thread B
------------------------ ------------------------
read x (0)
compute x (0) + 2
                 <context switch>
                         read x (0)
                         compute x (0) + 2
                         write x (2)
                 <context switch>
write x (2)
```

Now `x = 2` even though there were two `+= 2` computations. This effect is known as *tearing*.

Comment: Ok thanks, i've ust edited the topic cause you'right, i should have precise a bool with the volatile type modifier. Still i don't understand when you say that the access to the variable is neither synchronized nor atomic

Comment: I updated my answer. See the section below the first ruler. The last part is just me being thorough and maybe preventing followup questions ;)

Comment: Ok, i understood that the atomic bool force the storage in memory so that the reader thread can read the updated value correctly immediately. Unlike the volatile bool where the write can be done in registers and put in memory later so that there is latency and the reader thread read the old value whereas the update has been done but "in registers" only. I really thank you all of you :)

Comment: The exact behavior is architecture-dependent and you can't/shouldn't make any assumptions about this. E.g. on a multiprocessor system, even if the register containing the value is written to the processor's cache the changes may not be visible to the other processors on the system until the cache line containing the variable is written back to the main memory and even then, the other processors will only see the value after they reload the memory area in question. This topic becomes quite complex if you start looking at techniques like [snooping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_sniffing).

Comment: The whole point about declaring architecture-specific things like this as undefined behavior in the standard is to enable programmers to write code that is portable and doesn't rely on things that break on the second system it is executed on.

Answer (score 16):

The big difference is that this code is correct, while the version with `bool` instead of `atomic<bool>` has undefined behavior.

These two lines of code create a race condition (formally, a *conflict*) because they read from and write to the same variable:

> Reader
>
> ```
> while (!data_ready)
> ```
>
> And writer
>
> ```
> data_ready = true;
> ```

And a race condition on a normal variable causes undefined behavior, according to the C++11 memory model.

The rules are found in section 1.10 of the Standard, the most relevant being:

> Two actions are potentially concurrent if
>
> - they  are  performed  by  different  threads,  or
> - they  are  unsequenced,  and  at  least  one  is  performed  by  a  signal  handler.
>
> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below.  Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

You can see that whether the variable is `atomic<bool>` makes a very big difference to this rule.

Comment: Ok, there is a race condition, but eventually, the consequence are juste another round of while loop if the bool is read before the store.
For the undefined behavior since bool can only have two states, true or false. So when a bool variable is set to false, one juste have to modifiy one bit to make it true. So how can undefined behavior can happen here. Undefined behavior happens when there is a race condition and one thread can see an object in a half state which is inconsistent. So from my point of view, bool or std::atomic<bool> is the same in terms of code results.

Comment: @jedib: Undefined behaviour happens because the behaviour is undefined. If your asking for specific examples of erroneous behaviour that might arise in this particular case: without a memory barrier, the reading thread might see the `bool` change before its view of the vector is updated. Or it might not see the change at all, on a processor that doesn't guarantee cache coherency.

Comment: @Mike: Or, the optimizer might remove the `while` loop completely, on the grounds that `data_ready` cannot be and remain false forever (since that violates the making-progress rule) and cannot be false and later change from false to true (since that can only happen due to a conflicting write) and therefore the only remaining possibility is that `data_ready` is already true, the while loop is never entered, and is removed as dead code.

Comment: @jedib: Your error is in attempted to redefine "undefined behavior" to mean "any behavior that jedib can imagine".  The reality is much worse.  Code that exhibits undefined behavior is [**optimization unstable**](https://css.csail.mit.edu/stack/)

Comment: @BenVoigt What? How can the optimizer remove the while loop completely? Is there a real life example of your statement? The whole idea behind "volatile" is to tell optimizer to don't interfere!

Comment: This explanation does not apply to the code provided in the question. Race condition cannot create problems here. The only possible source of problems here is if the compiler reorders instructions inside `writer_thread`.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Race conditions can always cause problems.

Comment: @ben-voigt As been already pointed by @jedib exchanging the order of `while (!data_ready)` and `data_ready = true` does not affect the result, only may introduce little delay, so the problem in this example is not a race condition.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I'm using the C++ Standard's definition of "data race", not yours.  It's already been explained why jedib was wrong, and you are also wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Ben Voigt's answer is completely correct, still a little theoretical, and as I've been asked by a colleague "what does this mean for me", I decided to try my luck with a little more practical answer.

With your sample, the "simplest" optimization problem that could occur is the following:

According to the Standard, an optimized execution order may not change the functionality of a program. Problem is, this is **only true for single threaded programs**, or single threads in multithreaded programs.

So, for writer_thread and a (volatile) bool

```
data.push_back(42);
data_ready = true;
```

and

```
data_ready = true;
data.push_back(42);
```

are equivalent.

The result is, that

```
std::cout << "The answer=" << data[0] << "\n";
```

can be executed without having pushed any value into data.

An atomic bool does prevent this kind of optimization, as per definition it may not be reordered. There are flags for atomic operations which allow statements to be moved in front of the operation but not to the back, and vice versa, but those require a really advanced knowledge of your programming structure and the problems it can cause...