# How to check if thread has finished work in C++11 and above?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, multitasking

How can I check if thread has finished work in C++11 and above? I have been reading the documentation and I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void mythread() 
{
    //do some stuff
}
int main() 
{
  std::thread foo(mythread);  
  if (foo.joinable())
  {
    foo.join();
    //do some next stuff
  }
}
```

`joinable` tells only that the thread has started work, but I would like to know how to write code to check if the thread has finished work.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void mythread() 
{
    //do some stuff
}
int main() 
{
  std::thread foo(mythread);  
  if (foo.finishedWork())
  {
    foo.join();
    //do some next stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: `join` tells you that the thread has finished.

Comment: [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) is probably what you want to use

Comment: @knivil: It blocks until the thread finishes. Thus, you know that the thread is finished if it is joined but there is no "*thread is not finished yet*" option using `join`.

Comment: I did not say it will tell you that the thread did not finished.

Answer (score 10):

You may want to use [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), it provides higher level facilities where you can trivially check if the asynchronous computation is finished (aka ready): Example:

```
void mythread() {
    //do some stuff
}

template<typename T>
bool future_is_ready(std::future<T>& t){
    return t.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready;
}

int main() 
{
    std::future<void> foo = std::async(std::launch::async, mythread);  
    if (future_is_ready(foo)){
        //do some next stuff
    }
}
```

---

On the other hand, you may think simply using a "safe" (or atomic) flag works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> is_done{false};

void mythread() 
{
    //do some stuff
    ......
    is_done = true;
}
int main() 
{
  std::thread foo(mythread);  
  if (is_done)
  {
    foo.join();
    //do some next stuff
  }
  .....
  if(foo.joinable()) foo.join();
}
```

But, it **doesn't work**. While you think `is_done = true` is the last thing you did in `mythread()`; You may have created some objects of *automatic storage duration* in that scope, and since such objects are destroyed in the reverse order of construction, there will still be "some work" in that thread after setting `is_done`.

Answer (score 1):

You want a future. Start your thread with`std::async` and use `wait_for` with zero seconds on it. Compare the result against `future_status::ready`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) of [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) to check whether the result is already there. A simple way to get a future for an asynchronous task is `std::async`.

```
#include <future>

// ...

// launch task and get result future
auto rf = std::async(std::launch::async, mythread);
// get initial status
auto status = rf.wait_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
// loop while task is not ready
while(status != std::future_status::ready)
{ 

    // not ready yet, do other stuff here

    // 1 nanosecond timeout check
    status = rf.wait_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
}
// we are done...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my solution was to wrap the thread class, so I can set a flag when the function has finished its work.

Here you find the discussion for the solution [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757938/pass-parameters-to-stdthread-wrapper%20here)

And here is the working example: [Celma managed thread](https://github.com/Gemini67/Celma/blob/master/src/celma/common/managed_thread.hpp)

Comment: `volatile` doesn't prevent data races.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Obviously you did not read the whole thread nor look at the source code before hitting the downvote button.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The working example doesn't use volatile.  It (correctly) uses `<atomic>` instead.

Comment: While this technically isn't a link-only answer, it's still not much of an answer. It's better to include the actual answer in the answer - or suggest to close this question as a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then I apaologise. I assumed because of your comment and the single vote == downvote that it was you.

Comment: @Barry I cannot mark entries as duplicates (or at least I don't know how). If you think this applies here, then go ahead.