# Should SPIDs of OpenMP thread change if altering the number of threads in 2 sections?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, threadpool

I have 2 OpenMP parallel regions (I am using C++ under gcc under Linux) with different numbers of threads - let's say 4 in one and 8 in the other. Then, if I run `ps -T $(pidof name_of_process)`, 4 SPID are the same all the time, but remaining 4 change for every invocation. A sample output:

```
The first output

  PID  SPID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 7578  7578 pts/1    Rl+    1:18 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578  7579 pts/1    Rl+    0:57 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578  7580 pts/1    Rl+    0:57 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578  7581 pts/1    Rl+    0:57 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 19381 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 19382 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 19383 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 19384 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000

The second output

  PID  SPID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 7578  7578 pts/1    Rl+    1:23 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578  7579 pts/1    Rl+    1:01 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578  7580 pts/1    Rl+    1:01 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578  7581 pts/1    Rl+    1:01 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 22314 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 22315 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 22316 pts/1    Rl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
 7578 22317 pts/1    Sl+    0:00 ./rampack casino -i banana_cube.ini --start-from=0p5 --continue=100000
```

Does it mean that OpenMP is constantly creating new 4 threads when entering 8-threaded section and destroying afterwards (or when entering 4-threaded section)? I would assume so, but many places, such as [here](https://nanxiao.me/en/beware-of-openmps-thread-pool/) suggest, that the threads should persist and wait for their turn. I wouldn't be bothered about the internal workings of OpenMP, but [I have a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131322/what-causes-increasing-memory-consumption-in-openmp-based-simulation?noredirect=1#comment118706921_67131322) where memory mysteriously leaks and I am starting to suspect that some thread resources are not released (or maybe the memory becomes increasingly fragmented?).

So is it a correct behavior? I am using gcc, `gcc --version`: `gcc-8 (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0`.

Moreover, if it is the case, is it possible to force OpenMP not to constantly destroy and spawn new threads without making the 2 sections use the same number of threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably new threads yes. This is totally dependent of the platform and the OpenMP implementation. Moreover, this is unspecified by the OpenMP specification and so a compliant behavior. However, the GCC runtime (GOMP) and Intel/Clang one (IOMP) tend to reuse the threads as much as possible in practice. On my machine (with 6 cores), I am not able to reproduce your issue with both GOMP with GCC-10.2 and IOMP with Clang-11.0. Moreover, the following program show the same thread IDs which likely means they are reused:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    printf("%d\n", gettid());

    printf("----------\n");

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    printf("%d\n", gettid());

    printf("----------\n");

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    printf("%d\n", gettid());

/*
    // Update n°1
    printf("----------\n");

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    printf("%d\n", gettid());
*/
}
```

You should check the result of this program. If you cannot reproduce the behavior of your program on this simple example, it means the problem is specific to the behavior of your application. It could be the sign that you use multiple conflicting OpenMP runtimes. To check this hypothesis, please set the environment variable `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE` and look at the result. This behavior also often appear when you use nested regions.

---

**UPDATE n°1:**
With another section of 8 threads, GOMP on GCC-10.2 create new unneeded threads while IOMP on Clang-11.0 does not create additional threads. This might be a bug (or a very surprising behavior of GOMP).

**UPDATE n°2:**
While the behavior of a runtime is implementation defined, you can give some hints to the runtime using the environment variable `OMP_DYNAMIC`. Here is what the OpenMP specification states:

> The `OMP_DYNAMIC` environment variable controls dynamic adjustment of the number of threads to use for executing `parallel` regions by setting the initial value of the `dyn-var` ICV. The value of this environment variable must be one of the following: `true` | `false`. If the environment variable is set to `true`, the OpenMP implementation **may adjust** the number of threads to use for executing `parallel` regions in order to optimize the use of system resources. If the environment variable is set to `false`, the dynamic adjustment of the number of threads is disabled. The behavior of the program is implementation defined if the value of `OMP_DYNAMIC` is  neither `true` nor `false`.

However, using `OMP_DYNAMIC=TRUE` does not fix the problem on GOMP/GCC. Moreover, on both GOMP/GCC and IOMP/Clang, it limits the number of created threads to the number of available hardware threads (at least on my machine).

---

Keep in mind that the observed behavior of the OpenMP runtimes are compliant with the specification and your program should not assume no new threads are created (although you may want to tune the behavior for sake of performance).

Comment: I was able. However I had to add another num_threads(8) section below all. And then in the first tids were 14263, ...64, 65, 66, the second: 63, 64, 65, 66, the third: 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70 and lastly: 63, 64, 65, 66, 71, 72, 73, 74. The order was of course "random", I ordered it for clarity. Could you please add another 8-thread section and check?

Comment: @PKua Indeed, I got the same thing. I edited the question to take that into account. My guess that this is an unwanted behavior of GOMP/GCC that can be considered as a bug although this is compliant this the OpenMP specification.

Comment: This behaviour definitely has something "unwanted" in it, because using a code similar to yours, I was able to [reproduce what looks like a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267035/increasing-memory-consumption-for-2-alternating-openmp-parallel-regions-with-dif) on multiple gcc versions, so it may be eligible for a bug issue. And as you noticed, other OpenMP implementations seem to work correctly. Thank you for the help.