# Increasing memory consumption for 2 alternating OpenMP parallel regions with different number of threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, memory-leaks, openmp

When I alternate between 2 OpenMP parallel regions with a different number of threads repeatedly, the memory consumption increases indefinitely (tens of MB or even more). And it does this even in such a simple code snippet:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(16)
        usleep(30);

        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
        usleep(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As I have already discovered in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256527/should-spids-of-openmp-thread-change-if-altering-the-number-of-threads-in-2-sect), on my system 8 threads are reused all the time, while remaining 8 are newly created each time 16-thread section is entered. While creating and destroying threads may be an intended OpenMP behavior, constantly increasing memory usage looks like a memory leak. For 2 sections with the same number of threads everything is ok. Does anyone have any ideas what is the reason and what I can do if I insist on using a different number of threads in each section?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with GOMP form gcc 8.4.0 on a Ryzen 8-core 16-thread machine (7.5.0 has the same problem).

*This question is a stripped down version of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131322/what-causes-increasing-memory-consumption-in-openmp-based-simulation) making a minimal working example without unnecessary info.*

Comment: How do you measure memory leaks?

Comment: Here, the task managed shows always increasing memory consumption. In the original post I linked it continues for tens of GB ending in a OOM kill, here I left it only for couple of minutes. Valgrind does not show any "definitely lost"  at the end, while"possibly lost" or "still reachable" is only a couple of kB, so this might be as well extreme memory fragmentation

Comment: You might want to just file a bug with your compiler.

Comment: @PaulG. I may end up with doing this, but I find it quite sus, that a popular compiler with a popular implementation of OpenMP has a bug like this. But who knows... In the meantime maybe someone has idea what's going on.

Comment: Actually it would be nice if someone tested it on ICC - I do not have access to an Intel machine now.

Comment: @PKua I don't think many people use different numbers of threads like this. And even if they do, they might not observe this problem as long as they have enough RAM or don't let it run for long.

Comment: @PaulG. You may be right, in my case using the same number is also better than altering it, I just want to make it work anyway if possible

Comment: I tried the reproducer with GCC 8.3.1, 10.2.0 and Intel 2020 update 3 on a 64 cores AMD machine (forcing the number of threads to 128 and 64, and reducing the waiting time to speed-up the process). With GCC the virtual memory used is 32GB and the actual use increases steadily (I stopped after 2GB). With Intel, vmem is 8GB and resident is stable at 25MB.

Comment: FTR, the machine had 256GB of mem so waiting for an actual OOM kill to happen might have taken some time...

Comment: @Gilles Ok, so it seems to be specific to GOMP. In my actual runs, which are simulated by this waiting times and numbers of thread, it takes two days to consume whole 64 GB of memory and cause an actual OOM, but of course the code is far more complicated than a single usleep, which may amplify the issue